# If I remove a partition that was there first, does my second partition get access to the whole drive?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-8, partitioning

I have Ubuntu 13.04 and Windows 8 Dual-Booted (no UEFI crap, older computer). Windows 8 was installed first, Ubuntu second.

I want to remove my Windows 8 Using OS-Uninstaller, but if i do so, does that somehow move my Ubuntu Partition to where the windows 8 one was originally(420GB), giving Ubuntu the whole drive space to use, or does that just leave unallocated space, and leave my Ubuntu partition where it is on the drive (only about 80GB, making 500 total)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never used OS-Uninstaller, but I guess it will leave the unallocated space; then you can move/resize the Ubuntu partition.

From what I get of the [OS-Uninstaller wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller), it will just format the partition; in this case you can delete this partition (e.g. using gparted) and resize your existing Ubuntu partition.

Comment: so i can just literally stretch my ubuntu partiton using the unallocated space and have one big partition? or would it be easier to just wipe it all and start fresh? i haven't had this installation for very long, I wouldn't lose much...

Comment: Yes, you can stretch the partition.

Comment: awesome, thanks for finally just giving me a straight up answer :)